# Is there a difference between instantiation with parentheses or without?

Tags: php, oop, instance

What's the difference between these 2 piece of codes?

```
<?php

    $object1 = new User();
                     //^^
    $object1->name = "Hello";        
    echo $object1->name;
    class User {}

?>
```

And:

```
<?php

    $object1 = new User;
                    //^
    $object1->name = "Hello";        
    echo $object1->name;
    class User {}

?>
```

I get the same output:

```
Hello
```

So is there any difference if I use the parentheses or not in:

```
$object1=new User;
```

Comment: There is no difference whatsoever....you only need brackets when instantiating a new class instance if you need to pass any arguments to the constructor... personally, I prefer always using the brackets, as it makes that line stand out better in my editor

Comment: In the first one you have used the optional parentheses. Why don't you read a PHP book..

Comment: @TonyHopkinson actually I'm am reading PHP book and saw code examples when sometimes the author uses the parens and sometimes not so, I thought whats the difference

Comment: None, no parentheses = no arguments, empty parentheses = no arguments. If you think of a programming language as a user interface, the designer did not want to force you to use empty ones all the time, or never have empty ones. A very important part of programming is intent. By coding the parser this way the designer made this a difference in form, not substance. Oh and if it's a decent book, it should have been able to answer your question..

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript: With jQuery, CSS & HTML5 4th edition by Robin Nixon

Comment: Yeah well that should be six books. :) You've got a how to book, so it's assuming you'd know stuff like this, or doesn't think this sort of low level stuff is germane.

Comment: From the official php reference documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php ->

If there are no arguments to be passed to the class's constructor, parentheses after the class name may be omitted.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The are exactly the same, you can compare opcode of these 2 scripts:

1 script:

```
$object1=new User();
$object1->name="Hello";        
echo $object1->name;
class User {}
```

opcode:

```
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   FETCH_CLASS                                   4  :0      'User'
         1      NEW                                              $1      :0
         2      DO_FCALL_BY_NAME                              0          
         3      ASSIGN                                                   !0, $1
   4     4      ASSIGN_OBJ                                               !0, 'name'
         5      OP_DATA                                                  'Hello'
   5     6      FETCH_OBJ_R                                      $5      !0, 'name'
         7      ECHO                                                     $5
   6     8      NOP                                                      
         9    > RETURN                                                   1
```

2 script:

```
$object1=new User;
$object1->name="Hello";        
echo $object1->name;
class User {}
```

opcode:

```
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  >   FETCH_CLASS                                   4  :0      'User'
         1      NEW                                              $1      :0
         2      DO_FCALL_BY_NAME                              0          
         3      ASSIGN                                                   !0, $1
   4     4      ASSIGN_OBJ                                               !0, 'name'
         5      OP_DATA                                                  'Hello'
   5     6      FETCH_OBJ_R                                      $5      !0, 'name'
         7      ECHO                                                     $5
   6     8      NOP                                                      
         9    > RETURN                                                   1
```

Comment: Definitely a bonus for demonstrating the differences with the vld

Comment: that's an ANSWER! I would have difficulties to meet the 30 chars minimum :)

Comment: Seeing the opcode requires a special extension called the [Vulcan Logic Dumper](http://pecl.php.net/package/vld)

Comment: @BsD As Mark Baker said you need this extension ^ Or for small scripts you can use: http://3v4l.org

Answer (score 0):

Both are equal. if you not using any code convention then use which you like. I think `$object1 = new User()` would be useful over `$object1 = new User`. if you were passing arguments to the constructor.