# How to mock a Validation Rule in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, mockery

I want to mock a custom Validation rule (e.g. App\Rules\SomeRule). But when I run my test, it gives an `Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method...should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.`

I've read Laravel's documentation [on Mocking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking), [on custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules), [Service Containers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container), [Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers) and I cannot figure out why I'm not successfully mocking the rule.

I read [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/how-to-test-custom-validation-rules-in-laravel-5?page=1) but I'm struggling to connect it with my problem which is, "How can I test that my app is using this Rule". Or is that something I cannot test?

Here's my Rule

```php
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class SomeRule implements Rule
{

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // some logic, returns TRUE if valid.
    }

    public function message()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

My controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Rules\SomeRule;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoanController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', new SomeRule]
        ]);

        // ...insert in database, return json.
    }
}
```

My Test

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Mockery;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use App\Rules\SomeRule;

class LoansTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        Mockery::close();
    }

    /** @test */
    public function the_sad_path__when_email_is_invalid()
    {

        $rule = Mockery::mock(SomeRule::class)->shouldReceive('passes')->once();
        $this->app->instance(SomeRule::class, $rule);

        $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/loans', ['email' => 'whatevs@gmail.com']);
    }
}
```

I played with the idea of registering SomeRule in the AppServiceProvider. But that still didn't do anything:

```
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(SomeRule::class, function ($app) {
            return new SomeRule();
        });
    }
```

Code in [Github](https://github.com/akosipax/laravel-test)

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853235/mocking-laravel-custom-validation-rule-class-not-working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking Laravel custom validation rule class not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853235/mocking-laravel-custom-validation-rule-class-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to update the controller to defer the resolution of `SomeRule` to the container:

```php
public function store(Request $request, Application $app)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', $app->make(SomeRule::class)]
    ]);
}
```

This way, when we bind a mock object to `SomeRule::class` in the test, the container has the opportunity to resolve the mock object instead of a concrete instance.

You can simplify this one step further by type-hinting `SomeRule` directly on the controller method:

```php
public function store(Request $request, SomeRule $someRule)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', $someRule]
    ]);
}
```

For those on newer versions of Laravel coming to this thread, creating a mock and binding it to the container is now even simpler with some syntactic sugar:

```php
/** @test */
public function the_sad_path__when_email_is_invalid()
{
    $this->mock(SomeRule::class)->expects('passes');
    
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use like this

```
class LoanController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', new SomeRule()]
      ]);

    // ...insert in database, return json.
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between the two? In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules), it doesn't have `()` ; `'name' => ['required', 'string', new Uppercase],`

Comment: Never mind. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914283/is-there-a-difference-between-instantiation-with-parentheses-or-without/28914320

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm triying to mock the passes method of a custom validator in a test and throws 'Method.... does not exist' error