# Mocking Laravel custom validation rule class not working

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

I'm implementing a new custom validation rule in form submit. But I want to bypass the validation rule in unit testing. Below is the simplified of the validation rule and unit test class. What am I missing?

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class Captcha implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // assuming will always return false in testing
        // works fine when true
        return false; 
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'Captcha error! Try again later or contact site admin.';
    }
}
```

```
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Rules\Captcha;

class RegistrationTest extends TestCase {

    public test_user_registration()
    {
        $this->mock(Captcha::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('passes')->andReturn(true);
        });

        $response = $this->post(route('tenant.register'), [
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 1,
            'email' => 'user@example.com',
            'password' => 'secret',
        ]);

        $this->assertEquals(1, User::all()->count());
     }
}
```

EDIT: included `FormRequest` and `Controller` file as well

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Rules\Captcha;

class NewUserRequest extends FormRequest {

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', new Captcha]
        ];
    }
}
```

```
...

public function postRegister(NewUserRequest $request) {

...
```

EDIT II: seems like a bug in Laravel itself;

- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28468
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19450
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25041

tried the provided solutions but still not working

Comment: Your code registers the mocked instance with the container (implicitly by `->mock()`). Do you also retrieve it from the container? `app(Captcha::class)` in your code? If you don't but just do `new Captcha` then it won't work.

The docs at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#using-rule-objects give this example and that way, it's not mockable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class must be instantiated through Laravels service container in order for it to be mocked. The best way to accomplish this (in this situation) is to simply change `new Captcha` to `app(Captcha::class)`:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Rules\Captcha;

class NewUserRequest extends FormRequest {

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', app(Captcha::class)]
        ];
    }
}
```

I would advise against telling the rule itself to change its behaviors based on environments as that could result in a bit of confusion down the line when you are trying to figure out why the captcha doesn't do anything in dev environments but is failing in production.

Comment: Dude, it actually works, although is still looks like a workaround but agreed still better than my solution.

Comment: It does look like a workaround but it looks very clever and it gets the job done. The only thing is that you can do this only if no parameters are required to your rule. +1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an existing bug in Laravel for a long time, so the workaround is to not using Mock. So I will just bypass in `Rule` class when `testing` environment is present.

```
if (app()->environment() === 'testing')
    return true;
```